# How to Post data username password for login

Tags: php, ios, post, authentication

Hi in my application have a username password in my server so user need to login with username password from the device for that I have post the data to my php script and get response I'm doing it for the first time `login` process not getting proper solution please help me out.

My post code.

```
- (IBAction)submit:(id)sender {
     NSString *us = usern.text;
     NSString *pa = pass.text;
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/ios/?"];
   NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&Username=%@&Password=%@",us,pa];
   NSLog(@"%@",post);
     NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[url standardizedURL]
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];



  }
```

I have used the above code to post data after a Google search but the problem is how can i use this URL into my `php` script please tell how to use the URL to get the username password and pass it into proper URL to use in my `php` script

Comment: 1. Use SSL to protect the initial login credentials. 2. Do not save the password on your server, do not even send the password to the server, save a salted hash of the password. In the app when the user enters the password create a salted hash and send that to the server. Then when your server is hacked no passwords will be divulged since you server will not have them.

Comment: 'not getting proper solution" What is the error? You might check exactly what is being sent to the server with a network analyzer such as Charles proxy (free trial). That way you will know if it is a client or server problem.

Comment: @Zaph im not user is thiswill pass the data to my url or not then how can use this url in my php script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether I am providing the right answer for your question. If not, I apologize. I understand you are creating a login form in iOS, to validate the login details through PHP which is stored in your database.

**create a simple login form in PHP:**

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 

$username=""; // Mysql username 

$password=""; // Mysql password 

$db_name="test"; // Database name 

$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 

$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)

$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
```

**update your NSURL string:**

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.zzz.com/xyz.php";
```

**post the parameters**

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&Username=%@&Password=%@",us,pa];
```

Once you are successful with this, you can change as zaph said salted hash.

There are lots of tutorials for creating a username and password login function in iOS. i don't know whether you are a basic or new programmer. But try this and you may get some idea. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HrZR2SyeoSk.

You can go with JSON serialisation, if you expect to load data from server.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).